# Capybara finds textfield but does not fill it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, ruby-on-rails-4, capybara, rspec2

I have this textfield:

```
<p>
  <label for="user_email">Email</label>
  <input id="user_email" name="user[email]" type="text" value="user4@example.com" />
</p>
```

And in my test I'm trying to fill it like this:

```
fill_in "Email", with: "bla"
save_and_open_page
```

Capybara seems to find it, yet does not fill it... I also tried this:

```
fill_in "user_email", with: "bla"
```

and:

```
fill_in "user[email]", with: "bla"
```

But didn't work either, this is weird since I have 46 examples running and I'm only getting trouble with this particular textfield and I can't see what's wrong with it.

Am I missing something obvious? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: just a thought: your test has capital E in Email, and i think it should be small because of your user model's `email`. just a thought

Comment: I tried that and I got: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "email"`

Comment: if you can post the tests passing along with the view

Comment: Try using `fill_in "User email", with: "bla"`

Comment: Same result: `Capybara::ElementNotFound: Unable to find field "User email"`

Comment: see if you can find the element
`e = find('#user_email')`
And then see if you can set the element
`e.set('blah')`
And see if you can get its value
`puts e.value`